# PHP_SELF in yii action

Tags: php, forms, yii, action

How do you add in the yii form the action for PHP_SELF, I am currently using this:

```
'action' => '/site/contact',
```

but I want to replace the action to call itself again. How do I do that?

UPDATE:

tried removing the action in the array, now it does not go into validating the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Yii controller method [`createUrl`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#createUrl-detail) - calling it without params will point to current controller and action.

In views you can just call `$this->createUrl()`:

```
'action' => $this->createUrl(),
```

**Important**: do not hardcode actions like in your question. Always call `createUrl`, this will ensure proper urls if you change url rules:

```
'action' => $this->createUrl('otherController/someAction'),
```

or same controller different action

```
'action' => $this->createUrl('otherAction'),
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

Do mean perhaps a page refresh?

Just do `$this->refresh()` inside your controller action.

Comment: actually I can already render the page using `$this->render`.Right about now I was wondering if I would still need the action parameter if all I'm doing is rendering the page, but since I'm using `$_POST` values, I don't really know.